# Error: Request to Elasticsearch failed

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana

Kibana version: 5.4.2
Elasticsearch version: 5.4.2
Logstash version: 5.4.2
Server OS version: Linux Red Hat, docker container kibana, logstash and elasticsearch.

Logs does not display in ELK. What is the problem? How to fix the error?

---

> Discover: Request to Elasticsearch failed:
>   {"error":{"root_cause":[],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all
>   shards
>   failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[]},"status":503}
>   Less
>
> Error: Request to Elasticsearch failed:
>   {"error":{"root_cause":[],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all
>   shards
>   failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[]},"status":503}
>   at ip-address:5601/bundles/kibana.bundle.js?v=15117:28:10760   at
>   Function.Promise.try
>   (http://:5601/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=15117:82:22203) 
>   at ip-address:5601/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=15117:82:21573 at
>   Array.map (native) at Function.Promise.map
>   (http://ip-address:5601/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=15117:82:21528) at
>   callResponseHandlers
>   (http://:5601/bundles/kibana.bundle.js?v=15117:28:10376)
>   atip-address:5601/bundles/kibana.bundle.js?v=15117:27:29944 at
>   processQueue
>   (ip-address:5601/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=15117:38:23621)  at
>   ip-address:5601/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=15117:38:23888 at
>   Scope.$eval
>   (ip-address:5601/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=15117:39:4619)

Comment: Something went wrong in elasticsearch, please provide elastic logs

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21157466/all-shards-failed

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple websites

Go to

STORES > CONFIGURATION > CATALOG > CATALOG > CATALOG SEARCH > Elasticsearch Index Prefix.

Set a different prefix for each website, any random one for each. Reindex and flush cache on each store.

**Another Official Solution is**

Base on the bug filed in my previous reply, I modified the following file to fix the search problem.

./vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/Model/Adapter/FieldMapper/Product/FieldProvider/FieldType/Converter.php

private const ES_DATA_TYPE_DOUBLE = 'double';
--> private const ES_DATA_TYPE_FLOAT = 'float';

Answer (score -1):

Are the indices being created ? What does this show ?

GET /_cat/indices/

Comment: Hi Jack, this Answer would be better suited in the comment section of the question, (Not intended to demotivate you from helping).

Comment: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logs-do-not-displayed-in-elk-what-is-the-problem-how-to-fix-the-error/100058