# org.elasticsearch.cluster.block.ClusterBlockException: blocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/1/state not recovered / initialized]

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk

I am using ELK 6.8.9 all configuration is in my docker-compose file. It was working fine but when suddenly I am getting an error of

```
org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: all shards failed
or org.elasticsearch.cluster.block.ClusterBlockException: blocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/1/state not recovered / initialized];
```

This is how I configure ELK

```
   elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.9
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
    volumes:
      - /opt/services/data/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    user: ${USER_ID}
```

on calling

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cluster/health/balance_sheet?pretty'-- request
response -clear
```

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "status" : "red",
  "timed_out" : true,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 0,
  "active_shards" : 0,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 100.0
}
```

Comment: do you care about the data or can you delete it? did you mount the volume? can you share how you run your Elasticsearch container?

Comment: no I do not care about data right now I just want to configure my ELK in a right way and o I also mount the volumes  in my docker compose file as you can see in image and the elastic container is running inside a docker container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't care about the data (as you said in the comments of the question - you can delete your `/opt/services/data/elasticsearch` folder in your local machine

Do that while your container is `down` and then run `up` again.

Comment: but it will be a temporary solution what happen if I will care about the data  is there any way we can solve this problem with out losing my data

Comment: @Er.Garvesh right. First, let's see that it solve your current issue. I am not sure what you did but sounds like shards are corrupted. Did you take the container down in a middle of indexing or something?

Comment: Not sure about middle on indexing but some times i restart my server I was doing some changes in log stash files and i also tried to delete the index and restart the Elasticsearch but for after some times again i am getting this error. whenever I delete the index and restart the Elasticsearch it works for some time but its not a fixed solution for me

Comment: why are you restarting Elasticsearch after index deletion?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21157466/all-shards-failed  - Check this one

Comment: the restart solution is from 2014. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55111098/1011253 did you set replication to 0?

Comment: No i have not set Replication 0 , I am just using the default configuration                                     {
  "cluster_name": "docker-cluster",
  "status": "yellow",
  "timed_out": false,
  "number_of_nodes": 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes": 1,
  "active_primary_shards": 277,
  "active_shards": 277,
  "relocating_shards": 0,
  "initializing_shards": 0,
  "unassigned_shards": 245,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards": 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks": 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch": 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis": 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number": 53.06513409961686
}

Comment: so I guess this is your problem. Elasticsearch default replication factor is 1 which mean that you have two copied for each shard. Two same shards can't live on the same node and since you are running with only one node - the second shard because unassigned. You need to either change the default replication factor to 0 or add another Elasticsearch node

Comment: Yes i am running for single node but default number of shards are 5 . if am running  GET _cat/shards/fundapi-2020.12  Getting an output of API-2020.12 4 p STARTED    130   1.2mb 10.0.2.36 yCpzt6z  API-2020.12 4 r UNASSIGNED           
API-2020.12 1 p STARTED    133 989.9kb 10.0.2.36 yCpzt6z API-2020.12 1 r UNASSIGNED   API-2020.12 3 p STARTED  137 899.7kb 10.0.2.36 yCpzt6z
API-2020.12 3 r UNASSIGNED  API-2020.12 2 p STARTED    147     1mb 10.0.2.36 yCpzt API-2020.12 2 r UNASSIGNED  API-2020.12 0 p STARTED    128 980.9kb 10.0.2.36 yCpzt6z
API-2020.12 0 r UNASSIGNED

Comment: @Er.Garvesh shards and replicas are two different things. The default number of shards are 5 indeed - and different shards can live in the same node. If shard has relicas (like your case, every shard has 1 replica) you have 10 shards total (5 primary and 5 replicas). Those replicas need another node or you need to set replica to 0.

Comment: @Er.Garvesh any updates? did you try changing the replication factor?

Comment: Yes , I did  some changed set the replica to 0  now i have 5 shards only but after that I am facing a new exception in my logstash log Attempted to send a bulk request to elasticsearch, but no there are no living connections in the connection pool. Perhaps Elasticsearch is unreachable or down?"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::SocketException]

Comment: @Er.Garvesh I'm happy to hear! I will appreciate if you accept my answer above if it helped you. You can open a new question with the new problem and I'll try to assist

Answer (score 1):

### Steps to solve Elasticsearch 6.5.1 issue

1. Disable read only indices:

```sh
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/_all/_settings" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{ "index.blocks.read_only" : false } }'
```

2. Restart non master nodes
3. Review indices status by rest api:

```sh
curl http://10.146.64.42:9200/_cat/indices
```

4. Review cluster health:

```sh
curl http://10.146.64.42:9200/_cluster/health
```

After a while, the elastic cluster will return to green health status.

Comment: could you please give a reason, what the meaning/origins of the error is. a solution is always good, but it is only half as usefull without an explanation of why it occured.