# Indexing geojson file in elasticsearch with java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I got geojson file about 80mb size, when i am trying to index this document to ES in java method, ES stops respond and service is stopped until reboot. If i try to index this file via Kibana GUI everything works fine.

```
IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(indexName)
        .id(id)
        .source(content, XContentType.JSON);
    try {
      IndexResponse indexResponse = restHighLevelClient.index(indexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

and there is piece of log from ES

```
stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: all shards failed",
"at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onPhaseFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:568) [elasticsearch-7.10.1.jar:7.10.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.executeNextPhase(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:324) [elasticsearch-7.10.1.jar:7.10.1]",
```

any suggestions how to fix it?? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21157466/18157

Comment: @Igor, are you sure, this stack-trace is related to your bulk API action?? you need to provide more information in order to get some solid inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed issue, my elasticsearch has been running in docker container, and memory preferences in Docker were the same, 4gb as memory settings in elasticsearch.

So, ES was killed by Docker, when ES memory usage grew up