# Elasticsearch exception [type=search_phase_execution_exception, reason=all shards failed] error

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rest-client

i am new to elasticSearch, looking for the fix

```
@Document(indexName = "user_filters")
public class UserFilter {

    // Maps to _id field of ElasticSearch doc
    @Id
    private Long userId;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested, includeInParent = true)
    private List<Filters> filters;

    //
}

public class Filters extend FilterMeta data{

   //
}

public class FilterMetaData{
      Private Long id;
      //

}
```

i want to find filter using userId and FilterId, i am using elasticSearchRestTemplate and build query as such

```
Query query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withQuery(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                        .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("userId", userId))
                        .must(QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("filters", QueryBuilders.matchQuery("filters.id", filterId), ScoreMode.None)))
                .withSourceFilter(new FetchSourceFilter(new String[]{"filters"}, null))
                .build();

        SearchHits<UserFilter> searchHits = elasticsearchRestTemplate.search(query, UserFilter.class);
```

while hitting the api, i am getting this error "Elasticsearch exception [type=search_phase_execution_exception, reason=all shards failed]"

any fix for this?

Comment: It would be helpful if you add the stack trace.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21157466/all-shards-failed